Google sheets Query= using date and referencing dynamic sheets
I'm using the Query function to pull in the data from multiple sheets in the same doc/workbook into one sheet. The source sheets have the same data and columns but the data is based on the month.
The problem I'm running into is when I add a column with a date and then trying to use the SQL select query to filter the data. Here's my latest query that still isn't correct:
=QUERY({
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(July!A2:A),"2024/07/01",)),July!A2:I;
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Aug!A2:A),"2024/08/20",)),Aug!A2:I;
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Sept!A2:A),"2024/09/01",)),Sept!A2:I;
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Oct!A2:A),"2024/10/01",)),Oct!A2:I;
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Nov!A2:A),"2024/11/01",)),Nov!A2:I;
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Dec!A2:A),"2024/12/01",)),Dec!A2:I
},
"Select * where (Col7 is not null or Col8 is not null or Col9 is not null) or (Col1 = date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"') order by Col2 ASC, Col1 DESC")

No matter what I try, I can't get Col1 to pull in the correct sheet based on the date. I'm thinking it has something to do with the string vs date object and if so getting the correct format.

First, the formula uses an array to assemble the data from different sheets; the QUERY function does not do that.
Second, the IF used to set the value of the first column is adding text values, not dates.
NOTE: Handling dates in Google Sheets is tricky, especially when working with dates in formulas. Google Sheets manages dates, time and duration as serialized numbers, then uses cell number formatting to format how they are displayed.
If you want dates as the value of the first column, instead of a text value like "2024/07/01", use DATE(2024,07,01).
Another option is to change (Col1 = date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'). The first thing to do is to remove the date keyword. Then, instead of using - as the date separator, use / because this is the separator used in the IF functions.
NOTE: The QUERY function is a particular case as it uses Google Query Language. This is the reason we have to use special syntax for dates.

thank you for the direction.
I ended up converting to a Date but then it wasn't filtering correctly. Had to use TO_PURE_NUMBER for the date compare.
It would only compare correctly when the first date was converted to a number, adding "n/a" did that strangely. I then added the same date column again so I could use the formatting.

@RyanBeymer Thanks for your reply and sharing your findings. Without sample data is hard to be precise and concise. I might extend my answer later.

After the direction of @Wicket I came up with the final query.
=QUERY({
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(July!A2:A), DATE(2024,7,1),"n/a")),
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(July!A2:A), DATE(2024,7,1),)),
    July!A2:I;
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Aug!A2:A), DATE(2024,8,1),"n/a")),
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Aug!A2:A), DATE(2024,8,1),)),
    Aug!A2:I;
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Sept!A2:A),DATE(2024,9,1),"n/a")), 
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Sept!A2:A),DATE(2024,9,1),)), 
    Sept!A2:I;
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Oct!A2:A),DATE(2024,10,1),"n/a")), 
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Oct!A2:A),DATE(2024,10,1),)), 
    Oct!A2:I;
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Nov!A2:A),DATE(2024,11,1),"n/a")), 
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Nov!A2:A),DATE(2024,11,1),)), 
    Nov!A2:I;
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Dec!A2:A),DATE(2024,12,1),"n/a")), 
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Dec!A2:A),DATE(2024,12,1),)), 
    Dec!A2:I
},
"Select * where (Col8 is not null or Col9 is not null or Col10 is not null) or (Col1 = '"&TO_PURE_NUMBER(date(year(today()),month(today()),1))&"') order by Col3 ASC, Col1 DESC")

The additional date column was needed to be able to format using google sheets, the first column wouldn't format after I used the TO_PURE_NUMBER().

you don't need to call ARRAYFORMULA all these times. You just need a single call on QUERY or the array literal. (ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({},...)) or QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({}),...))
